# Load script or CDN after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

*I'm trying to run this ajax method for multi select drop down:-*

```
success: function (data) {
            var drop_down_option = '<select name="langOpt3[]" multiple id="langOpt3">';

            var check = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(check);
            for (var i in check) {
                console.log(check[i].branchId + ',' + check[i].validbranches);
                drop_down_option += '<option id="' + check[i].branchId +  '">' + check[i].validbranches + '</option>';
            }

            drop_down_option += '</select>';
            document.getElementById("checkID").innerHTML = drop_down_option;

        },
        async: false
```

*When i use the static multi select drop down on the html it works without red box, image shown as below :-*
[image: Drop down which isn't working dynamically]

---

*And which is not working is shown in red box:-*
[image: Working static drop down]

*These scripts i'm using :-*

```
<link href="~/css/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

*The issue as i see is that in case of dynamic my scripts runs before page load and thus this dynamic ajax don't show drop down,but in case of **static multi select drop down** it works because this drop down is before the page loads and thus the script runs over it how do i run ajax before page call or before these scripts run.*

Answer (score 0):

Just call your .selectMultiple event function in your ajax success method after inserting your select tag in DOM

```
success: function (data) {
        var drop_down_option = '<select name="langOpt3[]" multiple id="langOpt3">';

        var check = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(check);
        for (var i in check) {
            console.log(check[i].branchId + ',' + check[i].validbranches);
            drop_down_option += '<option id="' + check[i].branchId +  '">' + check[i].validbranches + '</option>';
        }

        drop_down_option += '</select>';
        document.getElementById("checkID").innerHTML = drop_down_option;

       $('#langOpt3').selectMultiple(
        //your code
       );

    }
```

Comment: $('#langOpt3').selectMultiple(
        //your code
       ); can you write more over it, it would be helpful

Comment: example of it over this method

Comment: Sir i need a example of $('#langOpt3').selectMultiple(
        //your code
       );  this code would be helpful